# How to disable SSL/TLS renegotiation capability in JBOSS7?

Tags: security, ssl, jboss7.x

I am running my web application on a JBOSS 7 server. After running an automated scan on the web application it alerts for a TLS1/SSLv3 Renegotiation Vulnerability. On researching a little bit I found that this can be fixed by disabling the capability of jboss server to renegotiate.
I am aware that this was possible in JBOSS 5 by specifying a property of the connector attribute. But this is not possible in JBOSS 7. 
Also I am using JDK 1.7 which the documents indicate has the fix.
Anybody has any thoughts on how to fix this vulnerability?